# Developer story open source dates bug

Tags: bug, developer-story

When I add 'Open Source' - A GitHub project, it always places it on the bottom of the timeline, but when I refresh the page it changes to the correct position (Back to top of the timeline, recent project that I've been working on). So I think it must be a bug.